# How to preserve escaped quotes in a python defined string

Tags: python-3.x, string, escaping

I have a use case where I need to pass a Request Body containing an attribute of escaped string characters.
Thus, I need to create a string with escaped double quotes, and preserve it in that form.

```
a = "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
```

Trying with the above and when print(a), python has actually un-escaped the string;
'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'

Though my requirement is, doing a print(a)
it should print it in its original form only:
`"{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"`

Any suggestions?
The POST body should be like this eventually:

```
{"name":"test24","description":"test1","schema":{"name":"schema_name"},"expression":{"format":"json","type":"blah","value":"{\"type\":\"query\",\"e\":\"account\",\"variable\":\"parameterReference1\",\"condition\":{\"type\":\"boolean_combination\",\"operator\":\"and\",\"sub_conditions\":[{\"type\":\"comparison\",\"lhs\":{\"type\":\"property\",,\"property_path\":[\"accountOrganization\",\"industry\"]},\"operator\":\"equals\",\"rhs\":[\"finance\"]}]}}"},"type":"sd"}
```

Comment: Use a raw string to avoid the ``\``s being interpreted as escape sequences, or just replace `"` with `\"` before sending the string?

Answer (score 1):

### Option #1

Use **raw** strings, `r''`

```py
>>> "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
>>> r"{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
'{\\"key1\\":\\"value1\\",\\"key2\\":\\"value2\\"}'
```

### Option #2

Use `json.dumps()`

```py
>>> from json import dumps
>>> s = "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
>>> s
'{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
>>> dumps(s)
'"{\\"key1\\":\\"value1\\",\\"key2\\":\\"value2\\"}"'
>>> dumps(s)[1:-1]
'{\\"key1\\":\\"value1\\",\\"key2\\":\\"value2\\"}'
```

### Summary

Here is an example with both approaches:

```py
import json

a = "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
a_raw = r"{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"

print(a)

print(a_raw)
print(json.dumps(a)[1:-1])

# they are the same
assert a_raw == json.dumps(a)[1:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, though none of these work in my case. I actually updated the description with an example POST request. Please see the expression.value